# Делегирование почты

Tags: email, dns, smtp, smtp-server

Занялся темой подъема SMTP-сервера для системы.

И возник хороший вопрос - Можно ли как то в MX делегировать не все ящики,а один определенный?

UPD :

Как вариант в MX указывать адрес своего сервака с приоритетом меньшим чем у других(если уже делегированно,например, на google). Но тут возникает вопрос что если просто до этой MX не дойдет(когда почтовый сервер будет проверять подлинность отправщика) или наоборот предыдущие сервера будут лежать(тогда письмо отправленное на этот ящик придет на мой сервак,надо будет его переслать нормальному получателю[конечно по таймингу определенному],в конечном итоге может скопиться целый пул дубликатов изначального письма,и когда этот пул наконец упадет конечному получателю он немного прифигеет).

P.S.

Надеюсь понятно пишу ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Был найден вариант :

Указывать в TXT записи информацию о том с каких адресов допустима отправка писем с данным доменом

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:X.X.X.X a mx -all
```

Кто сведущ в данном вопросе - опровергните или подтвердите данное высказывание.